# How openstreetmap get correct location of my laptop?

Tags: location, openstreetmap

I am very supprised  when using openstreetmap  to detect my location via openstreetmap site.

I use my laptop without any GPS receiver here. But it can point my location exactly to mets.

Could somebody please tell me how it can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, I don't exactly know how OSM does it but it may be using the browser api to get the location, the browser knows a lot about where you are since it can check you IP, you Wifi connection and things like that.

Google for example has a database of all wifi networks any cellphone has connected to with it's gps location, so they guess where you are without gps based on witch wifis you can see.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to get my longitude and latitude via mindmap but it is not exact as OSM do.Very supprised.It is more accurate than my GPS phone

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap, like most geo-based website, use the [browser geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_geolocation) to determine your location.
It is done by this [javascript file](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js#L32) on the OSM website.

The fact the position reported by your browser is more accurate indoor than GPS-based geolocation is probably because your browser use near WiFi SSID to "triangulate" your position (see this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system)).